# WebSphere Application Server 9.0 に適当なユーザーIDでログインできてしまう

Tags: oracle

WAS 9.0をOracle Linux 7.7に導入し、管理コンソールにログインするところまでできたのですが、ユーザーIDを入力してログインことに関して困っていることがあります。

その場で思いついた適当なユーザーIDを入力するだけで簡単にログインできてしまうのです。
aaaでもbbbでもログインしてしまえて、アクセス制御のかけ方について知りたく思います。

何卒宜しくお願い致します。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

管理セキュリティが有効になっていないと，管理画面へのアクセスに認証は必要なくなります。管理コンソールを使用する際に入力するIDは，コンソールにアクセスしている複数のユーザーの区別にしか利用されません（管理作業を中断した場合，同じユーザーIDを使用すれば，続きから作業を復活できます）。

管理コンソールのユーザー管理画面から管理ユーザーを登録し，セキュリティの「管理セキュリティ」を有効にして，WASを再起動してください。